# Rebuilding UE4 Plugin

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine4

so idk how to fix this issues, any ideas?
(I`m trying to rebuild plugin from Unreal 4.24.3 version to Unreal 4.26)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fscmv.png)

[when clicking on error shows this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4exXo.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that method now accepts a reference parameter rather than a pointer parameter.

replace

```
const TArray<uint8>* uncompressedRGBA;
```

with

```
TArray<uint8> uncompressedRGBA;
```